# How to convert a trained model to a function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I have finished training a model, what I want to do next is hand over my model to my colleages who know nothing about deep learning, I just want to give them a **function** that they can run without installing tensorflow or Python on their machines, may be just python (ideally I would love it to run on Matlab). Is this doable? How can I abstract away all or codify everything from them?

I read about deployment of models but it's all about servers and stuff, this is not what I want.
PS: assume a TF model for now.

Comment: If it's a TF model, then why do you tag PyTorch?

Comment: @akshayk07 I have Pytorch models, same question please. I can move my models to it if there's a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there's [onnx](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html) that aims at assisting in deploying trained models.
I do not have much experience with it, but I know it's not always a straight forward procedure.